# Converting the time zone in an automated cloud flow Power Automate

Tags: datetime, expression, power-automate

Hello and thank you for taking the time to read my post!
I just finalized an automated flow that will help me keep track of emails' flow (received) in a shared inbox. In essence, I am tracking the number of emails I get a day.
I set up the flow and was able to get it to work and I am getting a row added with the info I need (i.e., From, To, Subject line, Received Time, etc..). However, I noticed that the time stamp is not in the correct time zone. I read several posts and it seems like Power Automate has a UTC time zone set by default. I tried using an expression to convert to the correct time zone (EST), the flow did not return any errors but the time remained in the original format: "UTC".
This is the expression that I added" `convertTimeZone(utcNow(),'UTC','Eastern Standard Time','MM/dd/yyy HH:mm')` 
I would really appreciate any suggestions or guidance on how to best get this issue resolved.

[image: Flow actions]

[image: New attempt with date conversion]
[image: Date Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're converting from UTC, you can do it as easily as this ...

```
formatDateTime(convertFromUtc(utcNow(), 'Eastern Standard Time'), 'dd MMM yyyy HH:mm')
```

At the time of running this, the UTC date/time was the **5th of June, 2022 at 23:50**, this was my result ...

[image: DateTime]

Comment: Thank you! I am fairly new and still learning Power Automate. Do I add this action right after the very first step: "When New Email Arrives in a Shared Mailbox (V2)? Also, how do I look up the action you set up?

Comment: So the **Received Time** value, is that UTC is it?  If so, change the expression to be this in the `Date` field ... `formatDateTime(convertFromUtc(utcNow(), 'Eastern Standard Time'), 'dd MMM yyyy HH:mm')` ... and replace the `utcNow()` parameter to be your received time field from the email.

Comment: Good morning and thank you so much, again, for taking the time to help! 

This is what I used: formatDateTime(convertFromUtc(utcNow(), 'Eastern Standard Time'), 'dd MMM yyyy HH:mm')
Also, made sure to replace the utcnow() in the appropriate field. 
However, I am still getting the UTC date format but now with like added numbers and a letter (z) at the very end of the date/time stamp. 
I’m gonna try to add snippets of the edited flow/action and the time stamp output.

Comment: I just added two screenshots of 1)- The complete flow with the date conversion function, and 2)- the new date format output that I am getting when the flow is processed.

Comment: Do me a favour and remove the `DateTime Format` parameter and put the entire expression I gave you into the `Date` field and try again.

Comment: You are a genius! 
I did add the whole expression in the Dare field and now I have the format as such; 06/07/2022 9:31. 
I suppose that I can just text split the cell content so I can have the date in one Column and the time stamp (HH:MM) in another? 

Again, thank you so much!!!

Comment: That’s ok. **You should really flag it as the answer then, it helps others and rewards those who help.** Technically you could store the same value in two fields and then just format it differently, one for the date and one for the time.

Comment: I did flag it as the solution/answer, just now. Thank you!